# Counting Vowels Malfunctioning

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I have an x86 assembly function, which is supposed to count the number of vowels in a string in shape of an argument.

The way this function works is:
it iterates over the string by comparing each element with 0. If the current element is 0, then we stop. At each iteration `is_vowel` is called and depending on the value returned by this function `ebx` is incremented.

I have tested both `is_vowel` and `lower` several times and they seem to work correctly. But when I call `count_vowels` on this input it returns 1. That values is obviously not right, and is some kind of junk.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

int lower(int)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        mov ebx, 65
        cmp eax, ebx
        jnge _endif1

        _if1:
            mov eax, [ebp + 8]
            mov ebx, 90
            cmp eax, ebx
            jnle _endif11

            _if11:
                mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
                sub ebx, 65
                mov eax, 97
                add eax, ebx
                jmp _endfunc
            _endif11:
        _endif1:
            mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        _endfunc:

    }
}

int is_vowel(int)
{
    __asm
    {
        push [ebp + 8]
        call lower
        add esp, 4

        mov ecx, eax
        mov ebx, 97
        cmp ecx, ebx

        jnz _endifa
        _ifa:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifa:

        mov ebx, 101
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jnz _endife

        _ife:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endife:

        mov ebx, 105
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jnz _endifi

        _ifi:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifi:

        mov ebx, 111
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jnz _endifo

        _ifo:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifo:

        mov ebx, 117
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jnz _endifu

        _ifu:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifu:

            mov eax, 0
        _end_is_vowel:
    }
}

void debug(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n");
}

int count_vowels(char* )
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edi, 0
        mov ebx, 0
        _for:
            mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
            add ecx, edi
            mov eax, [ecx]

            cmp eax, 0
            jz _endfor

            push eax
            call is_vowel
            add esp, 4

            cmp eax, 0
            jz _endif

            _if:
                push ebx
                call debug
                add esp, 4
                add ebx, 1
            _endif:

            inc edi
            jmp _for
        _endfor:
        mov eax, ebx
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char arr[] = {'a', 'e', 'a', 'a', '\0'};

    printf("%d\n", count_vowels(arr));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mov eax, [ecx]` <-- Are your characters really 4 bytes each? It seems much more likely that they'd be single bytes.

Comment: Aside: in `mov ebx, 65; cmp eax, ebx` you don't need to load an immediate value into another register first. It's simpler to just `cmp eax, 65`, although as pointed out, it should lead to `cmp al, 65`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't used 1-byte register in my function, this line `mov eax, [ecx]` should be replaced to `movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx]`. `byte ptr` because a char uses 1 byte of storage and `movzx` in order to fill the rest of `eax` with zeros.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int lower(int)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        mov ebx, 65
        cmp eax, ebx
        jnge _endif1

        _if1:
            mov eax, [ebp + 8]
            mov ebx, 90
            cmp eax, ebx
            jnle _endif11

            _if11:
                mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
                sub ebx, 65
                mov eax, 97
                add eax, ebx
                jmp _endfunc
            _endif11:
        _endif1:
            mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        _endfunc:

    }
}

char is_vowel(char)
{
    __asm
    {
        push [ebp + 8]
        call lower
        add esp, 4

        cmp eax, 97
        jnz _endifa

        _ifa:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifa:

        cmp eax, 101
        jnz _endife

        _ife:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endife:

        cmp eax, 105
        jnz _endifi

        _ifi:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifi:

        cmp eax, 111
        jnz _endifo

        _ifo:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifo:

        cmp eax, 117
        jnz _endifu

        _ifu:
            mov eax, 1
            jmp _end_is_vowel
        _endifu:

        mov eax, 0
        _end_is_vowel:

    }
}

int count_vowels(char* )
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edx, 0
        mov ebx, 0
        _for:
            mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
            add ecx, edx
            movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx]

            cmp eax, 0
            jz _endfor

            push eax
            call is_vowel
            add esp, 4

            cmp eax, 0
            jz _endif

            _if:
                add ebx, 1
            _endif:

            inc edx
            jmp _for
        _endfor:
        mov eax, ebx
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char arr[] = {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f', '\0'};

    printf("%d\n", count_vowels(arr));

    return 0;
}
```